# Full screen webview on top of other layout

Tags: android

I have a game activity which is based on a LinearLayout defined in XML (but if it makes the answer easier I can easily make this a FrameLayout).

Now I wish to have an interstitial advert which will reside in a WebView. I wish to load up the url in the background while the game is playing and then, at a time of my choosing, splat the WebView over the top of my game's layout.

I have seen similar issues discussed on SO, but despite reading them, I can't seem to get this to work.

The essential code I'd like to see is simply "put this full screen webview over the top of my existing views at runtime".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LinearLayout doesn't allow items to stack on top of each other AFAIK

I think you'll have to either use a dialog, or switch to a different type of parent layout. RelativeLayout is what I would probably recommend but others would probably work too.

If you go with RelativeLayout you can do something like this:

```
WebView wv = new WebView(this);
//load up your url and whatever else you need to do with the WebView
RelativeLayout mainLyt = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.yourMainLayoutId);
mainLyt.addView(wv);
```